# Why JavaFX (3D) on Raspberry Pi doesn't work, although it should?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, raspberry-pi, javafx-3d

I think I've read all available solutions about problems with 3D under JFx on RPi and none of the following suits my needs. I had no problems with 2D applications.
But when I try to run 3D program, all the 3D elements are gone. After this command:

```sh
java -Djavafx.platform=eglfb -Dprism.verbose=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.experimental.embedded.3d=true -Dprism.glDepthSize=24 -Dprism.forceGPU=true -jar Brake_Check.jar
```

I get this:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.nInitialize([I)J
    at com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.nInitialize(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.initialize(X11GLFactory.java:146)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.paint.Material <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:53 AM javafx.scene.LightBase <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:54 AM javafx.scene.shape.Mesh <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:54 AM javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:54 AM javafx.scene.paint.Material <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:54 AM javafx.scene.SubScene <init>
WARNING: System can't support ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D
lip 19, 2019 3:31:54 AM javafx.scene.SubScene <init>
WARNING: System can't support antiAliasing
```

expected image:
[image: expected image]

actual image:
[image: previous image]

I've installed armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9

I will appreciate any suggestion.

**Edit**

After a additional research I've also added OpenJFX:
`apt-get install openjfx`
which makes some small improvements in total, but stil there is something missing.
Maybe I'll start from beginning. I used [tutorial](http://yuriymaltsev.com/?p=281) to set JavaFX for my Raspberry, then `libprism_es2.so` was missing so I've copied and renamed it from `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/arm/libprism_es2_eglfb.so` (I've chosen this one, because I thought if I was using `-Djavafx.platform=eglfb` parametr, it'd be good option to use) and now I've added OpenJFX, what else should be installed there? Do you think that newer version of sdk might be helpful? But on the other hand I'm afraid that my level of knowledge in operating Linux is too basic and instead of progresses there will be disaster  so I'd prefer to stay with version I already have.

Now, at the moment my application looks like that:
[image: actual image]

the output messages:

```sh
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 8192
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 16384
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 16384
Maximum number of varying components = 128
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 32
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 32
Graphics Vendor: VMware, Inc.
       Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 128 bits)
        Version: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
 vsync: true vpipe: true
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_LinearGradient_REFLECT.frag
lip 19, 2019 13:03:04 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.111
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: FillPgram_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: Blend_SRC_IN
new alphas
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Texture_Color.frag
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
```

Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you Google search `UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory.nInitialize([I)J` and exhaust all the links there?

Comment: I don't think that JavaFX version supports X11. You will have to try directly on the terminal.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the main solution to my problem was installing `apt-get install openjfx` which I already have mentioned before. After that, I don't have use `-Djavafx.platform=eglfb` anymore too.
The next problem that has occurred, was that everything was black. The problem seems to be in light (`PointLight`) added to the scene. After I've removed it, everything started to look much better but... there are still some defects. There is no shade on the boxes, `antiAliasing` is not working, and although there is only a simple animation, it's so laggy.

[image]

**EDIT**

quick update.
Everything is working fine as it should. I've restored light too in my project. 
What I've done was changing advanced settings in RPi.

`sudo raspi-config` then advanced, next `GL Driver`, next `GL (Full KMS) OpenGL desktop driver with full KMS`, save and reboot.

Target achieved.
[image]